# $\sigma$ - compact and locally compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the following sentence is true?

Each complete, separable and $\sigma$ - compact metric space is locally compact.

I suppose (but I'm not sure) it is a truth, becouse it was evidently used in the paper of  Łukasz Stettner "Remarks on Ergodic Conditions of Markov Processes on Polish Spaces"(108 p.) which I am studyng now.

full text of this work - http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~lototsky/InfDimErg/Stettner-InfDimMarkProc.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a counterexample let $e_i, i=1, 2, \ldots$ be the standard unit vectors in $\ell^2$, and $X$ the union of the line segments $L_i$ joining 0 to $e_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: @dawid: By definition $X = \bigcup L_i$ (a subset of $\ell^2$). The more interesting question is: Why is $X$ not locally compact? (look at $0$)

Comment: oh yes, sorry, i thought that X=l2, so.. the lack of the locally compactness doesnt seem to be obvious..

Comment: @dawid: A neighborhood of zero must contain a sequence of the form $t\, e_{i}$, $i=1,2,\ldots$ with $t$ small. This sequence has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: Is it complete?

Comment: Yes.  Consider a sequence $x_n$ in $X$.  If it is Cauchy, $\|x_n\|$ must converge.  If $\|x_n\| \to 0$, then $x_n \to 0 \in X$.  If $\|x_n\| \to r > 0$, then use the fact that $\|r e_i - r e_j\| > r$ for $i \ne j$.