# Locally compact Polish space is $\sigma$-compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, polish-spaces

I have recently encountered this result.

- Let $X$ be $\sigma$-compact, locally compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $X$. Then the space of continuous functions with *compact support* is dense in that of $\mu$-integrable functions w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_{L_1}$. [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66999/c-cx-dense-in-l-1x?rq=1)

I got that

- Polish space is *not* necessarily $\sigma$-compact. [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416566/is-a-polish-space-sigma-compact)
- $\sigma$-compact Polish space is *not* necessarily locally compact. [ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49707/sigma-compact-and-locally-compact-metric-space?rq=1)

I would like to ask if the following result holds, i.e.,

> Locally compact Polish space is $\sigma$-compact.

---

*Update:*

- As proven in an below answer: locally-compact second-countable space is $\sigma$-compact.
- From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168446/are-polish-space-and-lccb-space-related), every locally-compact second-countable Hausdorff space is a Polish space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a locally compact Polish space is $\sigma$-compact.

Since it is Polish, such a space admits a countable base $\mathcal{U} = \{B_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of open sets for the entire space; by local compactness, each element in $\mathcal{U}$ can be taken so that $\overline{B_i}$ is compact. Since $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{B_i}$, we have exhibited the $\sigma$-compactness of $X$.

Comment: It seems you proved that locally compact second-countable space is $\sigma$-compact. I'm confused because you wrote "Such a space does **not** exist".

Comment: @Akira Woops, apologies! I meant to write that a locally compact Polish space which is not $\sigma$-compact does not exist. I've amended my post to reflect this.